# Reading And Formatting CSV in Pandas - Problem with Indexes and Headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have this CSV

```
day        time       dni_tilt  d_tilt    r  g_tilted  dni  dhi  ghi  sky  top  code
                                                                       
2020-08-25 00:15       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 00:30       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 00:45       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 01:00       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 01:15       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
...                    ...     ...  ...       ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...
2020-08-25 23:00       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 23:15       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 23:30       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 23:45       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 24:00       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
```

I need to read it back as a DataFrame like this:

```
                     dni_tilt  d_tilt    r  g_tilted  dni  dhi  ghi  sky  top  code
                                                                       
2020-08-25 00:15       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 00:30       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 00:45       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
```

that is the first column must be a data-time index.
I tried with:

```
 colnames =['day','time','dni_tilt' ,'d_tilt','r','g_tilted', 'dni', 'dhi','ghi','sky','top','code'] 
 out=pd.read_csv(
                response_buffer,                     
                delimiter=' ',
                index_col=0,
                header=None,               
                names=colnames, 
                infer_datetime_format=True,
                parse_dates=[['day','time']])
```

but the result is strange:

```
                       dni_tilt  d_tilt    r  g_tilted  dni  dhi  ghi  sky  top  code
day_time                                                                        
2020-08-25 00:15       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 00:30       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 00:45       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 01:00       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 01:15       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
...                    ...     ...  ...       ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...
2020-08-25 23:00       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 23:15       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 23:30       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 23:45       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
2020-08-25 24:00       0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     1
```

Comment: What is strange about it?

Comment: It puts the label "day_time" on the first column. It should not.

Comment: Okay that is index name you can remove it by `out.index.name = ''`

Comment: Thank you. I did not know it at all!!!!

Comment: welcome! I have marked it duplicate.